# Help me correct this circuit with N mosfet

Tags: mosfet, circuit-protection, reverse-polarity

I am trying to build a protection for my circuit in case someone attached batteries or any power supply in reverse even if the other supply is normally attached.

As you can see I have 2 power supplies. Is it safe enough to protect the both power supplies and protect my circuit too.

Can anyone illustrate if i am doing wrong .

I simulated this circuit on LTSPICE and it shows correct. I am not sure what
 would you say about it.

Should I keep the common GNDs connected together?.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reverse polarity protection approach seems correct *(By the way, there's no need to put external parallel diodes for MOSFETs, because the MOSFETs do have diodes inside already)*.

The configuration has nothing different than this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fvID7G.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you apply this to your circuit;

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fqtvvX.png)</sup>

**If the supplies are isolated** then there will be no problems. But if supplies have a common connection at some point then some current (depending on the supply voltages and loads) may flow through the common ground connection between loads.

Comment: Thank you for this great answer .. I was sure that my work is fine , but i had to ask and make sure that i am doing the right thing . Thank you again